# WebCam that will work with all Recent Ubuntu Versions

Tags: linux, webcam

Anyone know of a decent webcam (Higher than VGA) that will work out of the box with the past few Ubuntu versions?

I will be looking to make it motion activated, so if there is anything special for that as well that would be good to know as well. It will probably be okay if the software handles that and the webcam is always on, as long as that won't tie up my video drive in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any specific camera in mind ? If you you can double check it against [this list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCameras?highlight=%28webcam%29) and ensure that your camera works fine.

Comment: Went with Logitech Quickcam Sphere, everything seems to work okay.